# Ignore Git notes getting pushed on push operation fail to remote repository

Tags: java, git, github, jgit

I am using **jgit api** and have my own git repository implemented using **GitServlet**.

Now on `receivepack.setPostReceiveHook` i do some operations internally. What is happening if the push is failed still the notes are getting pushed. I need to make sure on push error i am should also not push notes.

Here is my sample receivepack.setPostReceiveHoo code,

```
receivepack.setPostReceiveHook(new PostReceiveHook() {
                public void onPostReceive(ReceivePack rp, Collection<ReceiveCommand> commands) {
                    try {                           
                        System.out.println("Inside setPostReceiveHook ========>> ");
                        if (_resName.contains("smp") || _resName.contains("cfg")) {
                            System.out.println("Inside setPostReceiveHook  with res_nm : ========>> " + _resName);
                            System.out.println("pushing to all nodes as this is master");
                            SMPPushOperation.pushToPeers(rp, db.getDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                                    CFG_GIT_REPO_URL);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        receivepack.sendError("Unable to push... ");
                    }
                }

            });
            return receivepack;
```

My push URL,

```
git push https://sohanb.sys.net:8443/gitcontainer/demo-cfg refs/notes/*
```

When i look at my git repository i can see the notes are being pushed. In above code i do send error message.

How can i avoid pushing notes on push fail?

Please suggest

Comment: My previous answer was wrong. After digging into JGit's source code, I saw the post-receive-hook is only triggered for Result.OK commands. See https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/v4.11.0.201803080745-r/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/ReceivePack.java#L328 So the notes shouldn't be pushed on push fail. The bug is not coming from your post-receive-hook, it must be something else...